# how to get all the indexes of maximum repeated values in an array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

Hi I am new to Perl an in a learning process. 
I am having an array

```
 @array = ( 10, 40, 59, 40, 90, 100, 30, 40, 100, 20, );
```

I want to find the maximum number in the array and also want to know the index where the maximum number is present in my array.

I am doing

```
my $maxValue = max @array;
print $maxValue;      # displays the maximum number in the entire array

my ($index) = grep $array[$_] eq $maxValue , 0.. $#array;
print ($index);        # this gives me the index of the maximum number which was found in the array.
```

The output I am getting is 100 with index 5

But actually 100 is coming 2 times in the array: once at index 6 and again at index 8. My code only provide me the first index it finds with the max value.

How can I get all the index which has maximum value with them?

Comment: Assign the result of grep to array instead of a scalar variale

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my @index = grep $array[$_] eq $maxValue , 0.. $#array;
print @index;
```

Seems to be the simplest way.

Although for numbers, you really should use `==`, even though e.g. 100 is also a valid string.

Comment: Little more on `==` and `eq`. `100 == 100.0E0` is true and `100 eq 100.0E0` is also true. But `"100" == "100.0E0"` is true but not `"100" eq "100.0E0"`

Answer (score 0):

This is one time through the array to determine the max value and all the indexes:

```
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use Data::Dumper;

    my @array = ( 10, 40, 59, 40, 90, 100, 30, 40, 100, 20, );
    my %uniq;
    my $i = 0;
    my $max = 0;
    for (@array) {
        push @{ $uniq{$_} }, $i;
        $i++;
        $max = $_ if $_ > $max;
    }
    print "max=$max at indexes:\n";
    print Dumper($uniq{$max});

    __END__

    max=100 at indexes:
    $VAR1 = [
              5,
              8
            ];
```

Another way... without the hash:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array = ( 10, 40, 59, 40, 90, 100, 30, 40, 100, 20, );
my @maxs;
my $i = 0;
my $max = 0;
for (@array) {
    if ($_ > $max) {
        @maxs = $i;
        $max  = $_ ;
    }
    elsif ($_ == $max) {
        push @maxs, $i;
    }
    $i++;
}
print "max=$max at indexes:\n";
print Dumper(\@maxs);
```

Comment: Will not work for a list of negative numbers, though. Use a number from the array instead.